# WPF - Create a ListView that can Wrap its Content to an Specific Shape

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, wrappanel

If possible to create a listView that can Wrap its content to a specific shape instead of rectangular? So when its content touched the border it can go to next line

What I tried is create a shape by using Path, and create a listView on the top of the shape, and using a Wrap panel to wrap the listView content, but the wrap panel cannot wrap to the shape. Maybe can do a custom wrap panel and parse its geometry inside and do some conditions? but I am no idea to do it... anyone having idea to achieve this? Thanks a lot

[What I expected effect is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gi8QZ.png)

[What I did](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EDyc.png)

My XAML

```
                <Viewbox x:Name="LeftCVbx"
                         Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                         HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                         Margin="20"
                         >
                    <Path x:Name="LeftCPath"
                          Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" Fill="White"
                          Data="M 0 0 l 800 0 l 0 120 a 290 290 0 0 0 -250 250 l -550 0 z">
                          
                    </Path>
                </Viewbox>

                <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding ExampleList}"
                          Width="{Binding ElementName=LeftCVbx, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                          Height="{Binding ElementName=LeftCVbx, Path=ActualHeight}" 
                          ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                          BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2"
                          FontSize="22"
                          Background="Transparent">


                    <ListView.ItemsPanel>

                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>

                            <WrapPanel/>

                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        
                    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
                    
                </ListView>
```

Comment: You need to write a customized panel for that https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/browse/?redirectedfrom=MSDN-samples

Comment: [How to: Create a Custom Panel Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-create-a-custom-panel-element?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8). You would use that as the ItemsPanel of the ListView.